# Python "for i in" + variable

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
 #Euler Problem 1

    print "We are going to solve Project Euler's Problem #1"

    euler_number = input('What number do you want to sum up all the multiples?')
    a = input('Insert the 1st multiple here: ')
    b = input('Insert the 2nd multiple here: ')

    total = 0
    for i in euler_number:
        if i%a == 0 or i%b == 0:
    total += i
    print "Sum of all natural numbers below 'euler_number' that are multiples of 'a'"
    print "or 'b' is: ", total
```

---

With the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "euler_1.py", line 10, in <module>
    for i in euler_number:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

I tried to search for "for i in" + "variable", and other sorts, but could not find anything...

I have two questions:

1. What would you have suggested that I search for?
2. How can I solve this so that I can look for the sum of two multiples for any number?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
for i in range(1, euler_number + 1):
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a `for` loop loops using a series of values.  These can be, for example, items in a list; or these can be values that come from an "iterator".

`for i in 3` makes no sense in Python, as `3` is not a series of values.

To loop over a series of integers, use `range()` or `xrange()`.

[How does the Python's range function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738109/how-does-the-pythons-range-function-work)

Comment: Thanks for advice on what to look up. It seems as thought that is half the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for Python's `for` syntax:
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

It loops over any sequence of values, not just a sequence of numbers like in other languages.

Have fun learning Python, it's a great language.  Also, the Project Euler challenges are fun, so stick with them, and don't give up!

Comment: Thanks! The challenges are fun.