# Python 3 : List of odd numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to return a list of odd numbers below 15 by using a python user-defined function

```py
def oddnos(n):
  mylist = []
  for num in n:
    if num % 2 != 0:
       mylist.append(num)
  return mylist
print(oddnos(15))
```

But I'm getting this error :

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I didn't understand what exactly this means, please help me find my mistake

Comment: Duplicate of [Python "for i in" + variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738692/python-for-i-in-variable)

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort", which is clearly the case, as iteration over a range of integers is one of the first things [any decent Python tutorial teaches](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).

Comment: I'm downvoting because I found out this is a dupe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you're passing values to the function `oddnos`, you're not passing a list of values till 15, rather only number 15. So the error tells you, you're passing an `int` and not a list, hence not iterable.
Try to use `range()` function directly in the `for` loop, pass your number limit to the `oddnos` function.

Answer (score 0):

Because 15 is an integer, not a list you need to send the list as an input something like `range(0,15)` which will give all numbers between 0 and 15.

```py
def oddnos(n):
  mylist = []
  for num in n:
    if num % 2 != 0:
       mylist.append(num)
  return mylist
print(oddnos(range(0,15)))
```

Comment: Or simply `range(15)`.