# ATBS : Comma code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the comma code project for automate the boring stuff.I'm having trouble with the first if statement. I'm trying to output the string: 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. For somereason it's skipping the first item in the list.

**EDIT: The tutorial doesn't teach the join method so I will no be using it now. Also my program needs to work with all sized lists**

I think I should do the following but I keep getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first' referenced before assignment

```
if i < len(list[0:-2]):
    first += list[i] + ','
```

My code:

```
def myList(list):

    for i in range(len(list)+1):

        if i < len(list[0:-2]):    
            first = list[i] + ',' 
        elif i == len(list[0:-1]):
            second = list[-2]+ ' and '
        elif i == len(list[0:]):
            last = list[-1]

    print(first +second +last)            




spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
#list index 0 1 2 3

myList(spam)
```

My output is bananas,tofu and cats

EDIT: MY solution I googled was the global variable in the for loop

```
def myList(list):

    for i in range(len(list)):

        if i < len(list[0:-2]):
            global first
            first += list[i] + ',' 
        elif i == len(list[0:-1]):
            global second
            second = list[-2]+ ' and '
        elif i == len(list[0:]):
            global last
            last = list[-1]

    print(first +second +last)            




spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
#list index 0 1 2 3

myList(spam)
```

My output is now
bananas,apples,bananas,apples,bananas,apples,bananas,apples,bananas,apples,bananas,apples,bananas,tofu and cats

Comment: What is the _full_ error traceback?

Comment: Can you post the expected output as well?

Comment: See the edit I made

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to store them in different variables?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple just declare first at the starting of the function

```
def myList(list):
         first=""
         for i  in range(len(list)+1):

             if i < len(list[0:-2]):    
                 first =first+ list[i] + ','
             elif i == len(list[0:-1]):
                 second = list[-2]+ ' and '
             elif i == len(list[0:]):
                 last = list[-1]

         print(first +second +last)
```

***Next time try to put print statement everywhere and debug the code your self***

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm really doing this, but I just can't seem to get it right. I could not make it work with your code. I'd like to use global variables for the answer.

Comment: I executed the code and got output as you described you check it once again and by the using global variables is not good

Comment: That an indentation error just try now it have removed an extra space after print statement

Comment: Work comp, cannot access

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to insert the spam list and the call function in the end. 
Can you explain to me what the first" " does? Why does is matter that the variable first is a blank?

Comment: I just creates an empty string where you can append all the string and the reason why you were getting unbound local variable error because before even creating the variable you were trying to append with it

Comment: That makes sense. I get it now. 
Would you mind telling me why do I need +1 in the for loop. I tried it just as an instict, but I'm not sure how it affects the for loop. Is the range now 1,2,3,4. Without the +1 it would be 0,1,2,3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738109/how-does-the-pythons-range-function-work

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
def myList(spam):
    s = ''
    for i in range(len(spam)):
        if i == len(spam) - 1:
            s+= "and "+spam[i]
        else:
            s+= spam[i]+", "
    print(s)

myList(spam)
```

Or use `join` -

```
print(', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ', and ' + spam[-1])
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the first one. I keep getting longer and longer outputs

Comment: @LoveisHell try now

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the book right now ( 2 edition) so I'm a completely beginner. My answer to this exercise:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
            
def comma_code(source):
    source_string = ''
    try:
        if len(source) == 1:
            print(str(source[0]) + '.')
        else:    
            for item in source[:-2]:
                source_string = source_string + str(item) + ', '
            print(source_string + str(source[-2]) + ' and ' + str(source[-1]) + '.')
        
    except IndexError:
        return

comma_code(spam)
```

The result:

> apples, bananas, tofu and cats.

If the list is empty: " [] "

> 

If the list contains only 1 item: " [apples] "

> apples.

If the list are numbers: " [1,2,3,4,5] "

> 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

I could " print " a message in " except IndexError " to make a warring of empty list instead of only catching the error. I don't use " join " because the book doesn't cover that yet ( so I don't now what does ). This function only prints the result so I made another version to store the return value in a variable for other functions to use:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
            
def comma_code(source):
    source_string = ''
    try:
        if len(source) == 1:
            source_string = str(source[0]) + '.'
            return source_string
        else:    
            for item in source[:-2]:
                source_string = source_string + str(item) + ', '
            source_string = source_string + str(source[-2]) + ' and ' + str(source[-1]) + '.'
            return source_string
    
    except IndexError:
        return


print(comma_code(spam))
```

I will try to answer the original message:

You need to use a debugging tool and you will see why your first word is missing.
The problem I see is in:

```
if i < len(list[0:-2]):
```

Is not a global variable problem (all variables in your program are local). the " i " gets the value " 0 " and adds " list[0] " to the variable " first " THEN the second run the " i " gets the value 1 and its still less than 2 so it OVERRIDES the " first " variable with the value " list[1] ".

Comment: "Any thought ? anything will help. Thanks. " Is this meant to be a question or an answer? If latter, please drop this line and open a new question, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the length of a sliced list is complicated. Try this, no hardcode:

```
def myList(list):
    if len(list) <= 2:
        print(' and '.join(list))
    else:
        print(', '.join(list[:-1]) + ', and ' + list[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
***Try this below code as separate function:***

def myList(list):
returnString = ''
if len(list)>0 and len(list)>2:
    list_count = len(list)-1
    for idx,element in enumerate(list):
        ++idx
        if idx==list_count:
            returnString+="and %s"%element
        else:
            returnString+="%s, "%element
elif len(list)<=2:
    returnString = ' and '.join(list)
return returnString

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
print(myList(spam))
```

Comment: Too complicated for me at my current stage. Thanks still!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving this:

```
def listToString (list):
    output = ''
    for items in list[:-1]: # Grabs all items from the list except the final one
        output+= items + ', ' 
    output+= 'and ' + list[-1] + '.' # Adds the final value of the list.
    print(output)

testList = ['Apples','Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas']
listToString(testList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning python using this book and I found this solution using only the functions taught up till this problem.

```
spam = [ 'apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def Commacode(n):
    a = ''
    if len(n) == 1:
        print(n[0])
    else:
        for i in range(len(n) - 2):
            a = a + n[i] + ', '
        print(a + n[-2] + ' and ' + n[-1])

Commacode(spam)
```

Output:

```
apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```