# How to increment variable according to another's variable number?

Tags: python, loops, counter

I would like to write the following line of code, but with "i" ranging from 1 to 100000000, is there a better way to increment k's value according to i's value? I would like to increment k's value for each interval of 90 in "i".

```
i=0
while i<100000000:
    i+=1
    if i<91:
        k=2
    if i>90 and i<181:
        k=3
    if i>180 and i<271:
        k=4
    ...
```

Comment: Side note: You can form loops like this in Python a little more cleanly with [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1738109/2615940) for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with integer division:

```py
k = 2 + (i-1) // 90
```